# Find text when <br> is not in front of <img>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find out the content before `<img>` tag in my HTML if it does not have `<br/>` before it. And if `<img>` jas some other content before it then I need to add `<br/>` before it.

Comment: don't use regex in this case. use a dom parser. god knows there are plenty

Comment: [Do not parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/451590). Use a full HTML parser instead.

Comment: Also, what language are you using? (Does it have negative backreferences in its RE language variant?)

Comment: Here is all you EVER need to know about HTML and regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Have you tried using an XML parser instead?

Comment: Xpath route, if taken, would probably be along the lines of `//img[not(preceding-sibling::br)]`

Comment: Any dom parser would do the trick use JQuery!!

Comment: well I would have prefer to not need to use things like that because I only use a few HTML in my software...but I guess I don't have long range of choices

Comment: @castors33 A small script would solve your problem. I have mentioned below. Just have a look.You just need to include the JQuery file.Hope things work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this html code :- (This solution uses JQuery!)

```
<h1><img src="#"/><h1>
<br/><img src="#"/>
```

Now in one case you need to get the element before `<img>`

```
  $(document).ready(
function(){
 $('img').each(function(){
  if($(this).prev()==$('br'))
   {
      $(this).prev().replaceWith('');
   }
   if($(this).prev()!=$('br)')
        {
          $(this).prev().replaceWith('br');
        }
});

});
```

Guess this would solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly simpler and faster version

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('img').each(function(){
         var prev = $(this).prev();
         if (prev[0] && prev[0].nodeName.toUpperCase() !== 'BR') {
            prev.after('<br>')
         }
   })

})
```